# split dynamic content loading in multiple loading steps

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, bing-api

Maybe the title is bit off but I dont know how else to put it.

I have a script which allows to display Bing search results on keyup(jquery) The number of results can be set to a maximum of 50 results for each request. What I would like for my website is the ability to show only the first 10 results and by clicking a div each time other ten results would appear.

I can hide/show but that would mean that the 50 results would be loaded anyway which I want to avoid because of loading time.

Please take a look at this example to have a better understanding: [Google Powered site search](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/09/google-powered-site-search-ajax-jquery/search.html)

This is exactly what Im looking for but I dont understand the coding..

This is the actual script Im using: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVqwD/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just set the `web.count=10` then when they click on the div, set the `Web.Offset+=Web.Count+1` and load those results from the api?

Comment: Thanks, to tell you the truth I have no idea what 'offset' means or what it stands for, but I will look in to this and come back.

Comment: What it means is that number from which the next results will be.  So if you have loaded 10 (web.count) then start from 11.  Does this make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. But wouldn't the third request start at 21 and not 11 ??

Comment: (I have to make it work and then come back and except your answer)

Comment: Thanks I have updated my answer, it should add the number loaded each time plus 1, if that makes sense

Comment: Im still working at it, I just dont hope that it will eventually give me the same 10 results each time...:) (I think your answer is definitely useful so I gave credit for now)

Comment: I understand now (I think) But wouldn't that require a different script for each div?

Comment: What you could do is keep track of each time you click on the div at the bottom and just requist the next 10, some thing like Web.Offset+=currentCount+Web.Count+1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont understand your last comment. Just Web.Offset=number seems to work. I will try this with divs.